# React.js component not re-rendering children when the useState hook changes state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component, `NavBar`, which has two children: `NavItems` and `Icon`. When either of those children are clicked, their appearance should both change. A very standard functionality.

What I want in addition is to be able to set the initial state based on the screen width. For this I have created a custom hook that I have called `useMatchMedia`. Every time `useMatchMedia` is called, I need the state to be overridden, regardless of what state it currently has and the child components to be re-rendered with this new state.

I believe the problem lies within `NavBar` before the return statement. But just in case it doesn't, I have provided the code for my custom hook as well.

(Scroll to below my code to see my attempts to fix the issue).

Here is the parent:

```
function NavBar() {
    const matchMedia = useMatchMedia(false, "tablet"); // returns true or false if the screen width is that of a tablet or not
    const [hideNavItems, setHideNavItems] = useState(matchMedia);

    let onHandleHideNavItems = () => {
        setHideNavItems(!hideNavItems);
    };

    return (
        <Nav>
            <NavItems
                hideNavItems={hideNavItems}
                onHandleHideNavItems={onHandleHideNavItems} // onClick={() => onHandleHideNavItems(!hideNavItems)}
            />
            <Icon
                hideNavItems={hideNavItems}
                onHandleHideNavItems={onHandleHideNavItems} // onClick={() => onHandleHideNavItems(!hideNavItems)}
            />
        </Nav>
    );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Here is my custom hook:

```
function useMatchMedia(initialState, device) {
    const [passQuery, setPassQuery] = useState(initialState);
    const matchMediaRef = useRef(null);

    let widthType = null;
    let chosenDevice = device;

    switch (chosenDevice) {
        case "phone":
            chosenDevice = 425;
            widthType = "max";
            break;
        case "tablet":
            chosenDevice = 768;
            widthType = "max";
            break;
        case "smallLaptop":
            chosenDevice = 1024;
            widthType = "max";
            break;
        case "largeLaptop":
            chosenDevice = 1440;
            widthType = "max";
            break;
        default:
            chosenDevice = 1800;
            widthType = "min";
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        matchMediaRef.current = window.matchMedia(
            `(${widthType}-width: ${chosenDevice}px)`
        );
        const initialMatch = matchMediaRef.current.matches;

        if (initialMatch) {
            setPassQuery(true);
        } else {
            setPassQuery(false);
        }

        const target = (event) => {
            if (event.matches) {
                setPassQuery(true);
            } else {
                setPassQuery(false);
            }
        };

        matchMediaRef.current.addListener(target);

        return () => {
            matchMediaRef.current.removeListener(target);
        };
    }, [widthType, chosenDevice]);

    return passQuery;
}

export default useMatchMedia;
```

I have tried to use `useEffect` within my NavBar component, such as:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        setHideNavItems(!hideNavItems);
     }, [matchMedia, hideNavItems]);
```

That way I should get a re-render whenever matchMedia changes and as the initial state of `hideNavItems` is set to `matchMedia` that should update my state and therefore the children. This fails because it creates an infinite loop. I understand why there is an infinite loop but I also believe the solution is close to something like this.

I have also tried using `useCallback` on `onHandleHideNavItems` but that doesn't work.

I have tried using `useRef` to restrict the render to updates and not the initial render. This also does not work.

I'm a bit lost. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused about what are you try to accomplish, please check out this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-gagarin-d76bj) is this what you need?

Comment: I can't believe how close I was and overlooked that. If you post your "useEffect", I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yes indeed very close. I'm glad that I cloud help. Thank you.

Comment: I've found a problem with your answer. I need the state to be overridden by "UseMatchMedia". If "hideNavItems" is already false when the screen size changes to larger, meaning "UseMatchMedia" will also return false. The "NavItems" component will not re-render. Any ideas? I need "NavItems" to re-render every time "useMatchMedia" is called.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `useEffect` to reset the `hideNavItems` state back to `matchMedia` value whenever the screen width changes based on your `useMatchMedia` hook logic:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setHideNavItems(matchMedia);
}, [matchMedia]);
```

[image: Edit bold-gagarin-d76bj]

Comment: I've found a problem with your answer. I need the state to be overridden by "UseMatchMedia". If "hideNavItems" is already false when the screen size changes to larger, meaning "UseMatchMedia" will also return false. The "NavItems" component will not re-render. Any ideas? I need "NavItems" to re-render every time "useMatchMedia" is called.

Comment: Based on the current `UseMatchMedia` hook logic, the hook only checks for tablets _(second argument)_ and so, it will only called when the screen hits `768 px`. I guess you may need something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/window-resize-custom-hook-n21fo)

Comment: The problem with that is it is constantly firing. My useMatchMedia hook only fires when the screen width passes the specified value. I shouldn't have to change the useMatchMedia hook. I just need the two child components to recognise the change. The solution mostly likely lies in creating a new object with the same returned value, or maybe adding a state hook to the child components that takes in the props. I'm still searching every where for a solution.